# Why does my app design is left unconfigured when I change the elements id in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, algorithm

Here is the xml of my application. Every time I change one subject's ID everything gets unset. I don't know if it has to do with the fact that I first constructed all the constraints with the old ID and when you try to change Android Studio don't accept the change and this somehow leads to this mistake.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Calcular"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputEditText" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Resultado"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="Encontre a melhor opção para abastecimento no seu carro"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="462dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText3"
        android:layout_width="327dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:hint="Preço do Álcool ex: 1.90"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="327dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="Preço da Gasolina ex: 2.60"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputEditText3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: yes, changing the ID in the xml will not propagate the change and other views will still be using the old ID, better way would be selecting the id to be changed, right click to open options menu, choose`refractor-> Rename`, it's worth knowing the keyboard shortcut as well

Comment: Thanks for this tip, really helped me